# $i--; iterator gets caught in infinite loop - for loop php

Tags: php, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am using a basic `for` loop with incrementing iterators to check for duplicates:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'];

for ($i = 0; $i < $length-1; $i++) {
  if ($array[$i] == $array[$i + 1]) {
    //delete $array[$i + 1]
    $i--;
  } 
}
```

I would like to compare all elements with the next one in the array. If there is a duplicate, I have a helper function to delete it but then want to reset `$i` back one to compare it again with the next element after the one that was deleted using `$i--;`. However, when I do this, I get stuck in an infinite loop. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If `$i` is 0 and you add 1 `++` and then subtract 1 `--`, what is `$i`?

Comment: It gets stuck because the `for` increases it by 1, and your `$i--;` reduces it by one. So it never actually gets increased. It does this for **every** iteration, not just where the array matches.

Comment: sorry! I meant that it is in the `for` loop - will update now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decrement `$i` after incrementing it, so it will always toggle between `0` and `1`.

There is a function in PHP for what you are trying to do: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php)

---

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'];

$last = $array[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  if ($array[$i]==$last) {
    unset($array[$i]); // delete element
  }
  else $last = $array[$i]; // remember value
}

var_dump($array);
```

produces

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" [5]=> string(1) "d" }
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly! I do not want to use array_unique() because I need to actually delete the users (with the helper function). Is there anyway to set the counter back by one so then when it increments it'll be on the same record as it was before deleting? So, if I'm on [1], comparing [1] and [2], I then delete [2]. I then want to compare [1] to [3].

Comment: You have to nest two `for` statements for that. Store $array[$i] into a var, use another `for` to walk the same array count index by another counter eg. $j, and compare each loop ($var == $array[$j]? delete($array[$j]))

Comment: Easier would be to store the last value you have seen and not deleted and compare to that while iterating further on. So you put it the first value for example in `$last`, start the loop with the second value (`$i=1`), and every value that not gets deleted should overwrite `$last`  (`$last = $array[$i]`). I try to add something like that to the answer,

Comment: syck - thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, this still didn't work and doesn't go back to [1]. Aedix - I'm not sure what you mean, could you perhaps share code as an example?

Comment: @chloealee Sorry for the bugs, I only had a few minutes, and I let myself confuse by your code. Now it works and should produce the intended output.

Comment: and as you can see, no `$i--;` in there :-)

Comment: this is great - thank you so much for all your help, @syck!

Comment: No reason, it was fun for me and thanks for the appreciation.